# deleting from custom list mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

My code is running but not properly.please if anyone can help with this issue.when i try to delete some items from my todolist app custom list it is working but not properly like it adds another content on the title of the web page.

```
app.post("/delete",function(req,res){
  const checkedID=(req.body.checker);
  const listName=req.body.listName;
  if (listName==="Today") {
    Todolist.findByIdAndRemove(checkedID,function(err){
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
      }
      else{
        console.log("deleted succesfully")
        res.redirect("/");
      }
    });
    }
    else{
    List.findOneAndUpdate({name:listName},{$pull:{items:{_id:checkedID}}},function(err,results){
      if(!err){
        res.redirect("/"+listName);
      }
      else{
        console.log(err);
      }
    });

    }


});
```

---

i think i have made a simple error but i can't figure it out

Comment: why for remove you used Todolist and for update you used List , do you have different models ?

Comment: also share you front-end code

Comment: yes i do have different modules